# I need to loop from one array to another new array

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

I'm sorting windows last logon, and I want to use only variables instead of file, in file it's easy to manipulate it but slow since it will use disk access not ram.

```
# lastlogon
$UserProperty = @{n="User";e={(New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $_.ReplacementStrings[1]).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])}}
$TypeProperty = @{n="Action";e={if($_.EventID -eq 7001) {"Logon"} else {"Logoff"}}}
$TimeProperty = @{n="Time";e={$_.TimeGenerated}}
$MachineNameProperty = @{n="MachinenName";e={$_.MachineName}}
$last1=Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon -ComputerName localhost | select $UserProperty,$TypeProperty,$TimeProperty,$MachineNameProperty

foreach ($line in $last1) {
         $l = $line -split ' '
         $user1 = $l[0]
         $user0 = $user1 -replace ';'
         $user2 = $user0.Substring($user0.IndexOf("\")+1,$user0.Length-$user0.IndexOf("\")-1)
         $t1 = $l[2] -replace 'Time='
         $t2 = $l[3] -replace ';'
         $time1 = $t1+' '+$t2
         $last21 = $user2+' '+$time1
}
```

`$last21` will only get the last data. If I change it to `+=` it will be one line.  I want my `$last21` like this:

```bsh
PS > $last21
user1 1/2/20 150000
user1 1/1/20 120000
user2 1/1/20 010000
.
.
.
```

Thanks and more power!!!

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

You can do these who ever you are ;)

```
$last21 = $last1
$c = 0
foreach ($line in $last1) {
    $l = $line -split ' '
    $user1 = $l[0]
    $user0 = $user1 -replace ';'
    $user2 = $user0.Substring($user0.IndexOf("\") + 1, $user0.Length - $user0.IndexOf("\") - 1)
    $t1 = $l[2] -replace 'Time='
    $t2 = $l[3] -replace ';'
    $t3 = $t1 + ' ' + $t2
    $last21[$c] = $user2 + ' ' + $t3
    $c += 1
}
$last2 = $last21 | sort -Descending
```

Comment: In PpwerShell, it is better to use the pipeline rather than using a (`$c`) counter (I guess this will also cause an error in `Set-Strictmode -Version 3`). Meaning something like: `$last2 = foreach ($line in $last1) { ... ; $user2 + ' ' + $t3 } | sort -Descending`